# How to get output after running Apache Spark job on web

Tags: java, web-services, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm a student learning Hadoop and Apache Spark. I wanna know how to get output from Apache Spark Job on web.

following is so simple php code to run Apache Spark Job on web because I just want to test it.

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("spark-submit --class stu.ac.TestProject.App --master spark://localhost:7077 /TestProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar");
?>
```

and following is a example java code for Apache Spark job.

```
public class App 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaSparkPi");
    sparkConf.setMaster("spark://localhost:7077");
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    int slices = (args.length == 1) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 2;
    int n = 100000 * slices;
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        l.add(i);
    }
    JavaRDD<Integer> dataSet = jsc.parallelize(l, slices);

    JavaRDD<Integer> countRDD = dataSet.map(new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
        public Integer call(Integer arg0) throws Exception {
            double x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            double y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            return (x * x + y * y < 1) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    });

    int count = countRDD.reduce(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        public Integer call(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) throws Exception {
            return arg0 + arg1;
        }
    });

    System.out.println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n);
    jsc.stop();
}
}
```

I want to get only standard output but after running the code I got empty output. I build this java code on maven project so also checked its running on cmd mode.

How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance for your answer and sorry for my poor english. If you don't understand my question please make a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A job's output stays in the job so to speak. Even if Spark is fast, it's not so fast that it can instantly generate the data. A job is run a on a distributed cluster, this takes some time.

You'll have to write your output somewhere, typically into a database that you can then query from your web application. You don't start your job from your web application, it should rather be scheduled depending on your application's needs.

If you are running your job from within a Java, Scala, or Python job, you can retrieve its result directly. With PHP I'm not so sure.

Comment: I want to get the output when job is finished. if I write output into a database how to know end of the job?

Comment: If you simply want to display a job's Java System.out, you should look for an answer regarding that, that's not specific to Spark. Otherwise  you would display what is currently in your database and run jobs on a scheduled basis.

Comment: this problem is regarding Spark because I tested 'echo shell_exec("ls -al"' that submitted output but 'echo shell_exec("spark-submit --class ssm.pnu.TestP....")' is not working.

Comment: `ls` is a command-line tool. Have you tried executing a non-Spark Java application?

Comment: Ah.. you're right. this is my mistake that I didn't know.

Comment: Yep. I know but I realized my mistake that my question is not core of this problem because of you :) thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [JobServer Api](https://github.com/ooyala/spark-jobserver) for Apache Spark